# what is the major difference between transfer() and receive() function in this code.?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

```
contract Funder{
    uint public numOfFunders;

    mapping(uint256 => address) private funders;

    receive() external payable {}

    function transfer() external payable {
        funders[numOfFunders] = msg.sender;
    }

    function withdraw(uint withdrawAmount) external{
        require(withdrawAmount <= 2 ether,"cannot withdraw more than 2 ether");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(withdrawAmount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Receive() add the msg.value to the balance of the smart contract, transfer() does the same AND adds the msg.sender to the funders mapping, in this case, always at index 0 since there is no way to increment numOfFunders